# AngularJS - Can filter mutate the result?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible for filter to `mutate` the result of the filter?
Suppose I want to write a filter that would actually add something to the previous list

```
module.filter('family',function(){
  return function(data,expand){
    var people = [];
    data.forEach(function(child){
      people.push(child);
      // here add something extra
      if (expand){
        // the problem here I just want to demonstrate is that I have to 
        // generate the father and mother on the fly.
        people.push(angular.$copy(child.father,{}));
        people.push(angular.$copy(child.mother,{}));
      }
    });
    return people;
  }
});
```

what I want to do next is:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in children|faimly:true">
    {{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Would it be safe to do this? I am affraid that this may cause multiple `$digest()` or `$apply()`

**edit**

probably the main problem here, is the fact that I have to return every **time the same object** (because `$watch` would compare `===`, and afaik there are at least 2 `$digest` going on on the first render). Therefore I can not `generate` the objects in the filter - would cause infinite loop. Am I right?

Is there any option to `generate` the extra results in the filter? Can I cache them somehow, or trick angular to think that they are the same ?

Comment: Perhaps one of the things you should not do is premature optimization. Optimize this to not use a filter when you hit performance bottlenecks. Till then choose the most easiest way.

Comment: You can do the logic in a function inside your controller as a first step and see if it is enough for your goal. ng-repeat="person in getChildren(true)"

Comment: my real life example are recurring events, that I want to generate for each day. So it would be great if I could generate a list of instances of the recurring event based on the day I am currently showing.